# Create a new column that counts ";" in a row

Tags: python

I'm having the following table sample:

How can I create a new column that counts the number of ';' in each row ?

```
S Locations
2111 31672;0
2113 31965;0;;
2100 0;78464;1
```

I tried the following loop:

```
total = 0
countlocation =[]
for line in data:
    if line is None:
        numSlashes= 0
    else:
        numSlashes = line.count(';')
    total += numSlashes + 1
    countlocation.append(total)
    total = 0
```

Comment: How is your `data` defined?

Comment: Is this a dataframe or a different data structure with 'columns'?

Comment: What do you want in the end. It looks like your code is making a single list, but that won't really capture the different numbers of `;` in a single line for each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assuming from your data structure that " " (blank) is your column delimiter and you now have two columns. The following should add a third column with the total number of semicolons:

```
total = 0
countlocation =[]
for line in data:
    if line is None:
        numSlashes= 0
    else:
        numSlashes = line.count(';')

    total += numSlashes + 1
    #countlocation.append(line + " " + total) #for total of all rows
    countlocation.append(line + " " + numSlashes) #for total of this row
    total = 0
```

Note that I commented out the line that uses total because it keeps a running total of all of the lines and that is not what you asked for. I left it just in case that is what you wanted.